# SQL select query inner join many to many refactor

Tags: sql

I have a many to many relationship between entries and keywords with a join table entries_keywords. I want to fetch all entries for both the keys 'wake' and 'up'. The only way I came up with is this. If I want to throw in another search word it gets even worse. How do you refactor this? Is there another way to join it than using subqueries?

```
select * 
from 
(
    select * 
    from entries e 
    inner join entries_keywords ek 
        on e.id = ek.entry_id 
    inner join keywords k 
        on ek.keyword_id = k.id 
    where k.key = 'wake'
) e 
inner join entries_keywords ek 
    on e.id = ek.entry_id 
inner join keywords k 
    on ek.keyword_id = k.id 
where k.key = 'up';
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve records that have ***both*** `wake` and `up` or just one or the other?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve entries that have at least one of the keywords, you can do:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    entries a
INNER JOIN
    entries_keywords b ON a.id = b.entry_id
INNER JOIN
    keywords c ON b.keyword_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.key IN ('wake', 'up')
```

If you want to retrieve entries that have ALL of the keywords in the list, add `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    entries a
INNER JOIN
    entries_keywords b ON a.id = b.entry_id
INNER JOIN
    keywords c ON b.keyword_id = c.id
WHERE
    c.key IN ('wake', 'up')
GROUP BY
    a.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Where `2` is the number of keywords in the list you're checking on.

Comment: Thanks but using the last one with having, I'm getting results that only matches one of the words in addition to the ones that matches both. Only entries matching _both_ of the keywords must be included in the result.

Comment: @OpptattJobber, that is weird and should not happen. My guess is you have some sort of duplication in your data. Is the many-to-many table unique across the combination of *just* the `entry_id` and `keyword_id` columns? Also, in the `keywords` table, can there be keywords that appear more than once but with different ids?

Comment: The query I posted on the top does exactly that but it's ugly and possibly slower than fetching without subqueries. Your query on the same data returns more entries. One id per keyword, each entry is unique.

Comment: @OpptattJobber, I think GROUPing by only one column while selecting multiple is what is maybe screwing it up as you're not using MySQL. What columns do you need to select from the `entries` table?

Comment: I did have some duplication in my join table! Thanks for helping me with that! Your query works beautifully but my original query outperforms it using my current indexes and limits. How should I apply indexes to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your need right, you can use a `UNION` to join the 2 queries results in a list:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN entries_keyworkds ek
    ON e.id = ek.entry_id
INNER JOIN keywords k
    ON ek.keywork_id = k.id
WHERE k.key = 'WAKE'

UNION

SELECT *
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN entries_keyworkds ek
    ON e.id = ek.entry_id
INNER JOIN keywords k
    ON ek.keywork_id = k.id
WHERE k.key = 'up'
;
```

This will return all entries for "wake" + all entries for "up".

To find entries with both keys, use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN entries_keyworkds ek
    ON e.id = ek.entry_id
INNER JOIN keywords k
    ON ek.keywork_id = k.id
WHERE k.key = 'WAKE'

INTERSECT

SELECT *
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN entries_keyworkds ek
    ON e.id = ek.entry_id
INNER JOIN keywords k
    ON ek.keywork_id = k.id
WHERE k.key = 'up'
;
```

This will return all entries that have both keywords.

Comment: If an entry has both keywords `wake` and `up`, you will have duplicate entries in the result-set due to the `UNION ALL`. Use just `UNION` instead to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I'll edit my answer. Think I'm just tired (some bad sleeping nights).

Comment: Thanks, this is working but I think it will be slower than the one I already have since you search the whole db instead of searching the subqueries.

Comment: You will have to compare the execution plans and/or times to know, but I think the execution plan is almost the same for SQL Server.